# how to dynamically decrypt data in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I wrote a lua dissector for my protocol in wireshark: `my.lua`. The problem is that my protocol uses AES encryption for the data, the encryption AES key is different for each session.

Now I hardcoded the 16-byte-aes-key in  `my.lua`, but every time before I start capturing or load some saved packets, I need to modify the hardcoded value, which is very inconvenient.

Is there anyway in wireshark that can allow user input something? For example, a popup dialog says: `"please input the aes key"` and after user input it, the lua script use it to do the decryption.

Comment: hello, I'm doing similar things, can you share your lua script about dissector which can decrypt AES data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the Prefs API. Creating a new preference is as simple as setting the index while reading the pref is reading the index:

```
your_proto = Proto("yourproto", "Your Proto")
your_proto.prefs.key = Pref.string("Decryption key", "", "128-bit AES key (in hex)")

function your_proto.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
    local decryption_key = your_proto.prefs.key
    decrypt(tvb, tvb())  -- assume suitable "decrypt" routine
end
```

Then you can right-click the protocol tree, select Protocol preferences and modify your setting. See https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html#lua_class_Pref for the docs.

(Shameless plug:) An example of using the Preferences API with the luagcrypt library (for faster AES decryption) can be found here:

- [Wireshark Lua dissector for kdnet](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/kdnet/blob/master/kdnet.lua)
- [luagcrypt, a Lua binding to Libgcrypt](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/luagcrypt)